# What does C++ if-Statement with double parantheses do?

Tags: c++, unix

I have stumbled upon an `if` statement where the condition is actually an assignment and I don't really understand what it does. Now, I found a similar Question with extensive answers but I still don't quite understand, what my snippet does:

```
if ((x = !x))
    /* some code */
```

The similar question I found is this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs

One user states, that

> ((…)) double parentheses surround an arithmetic instruction, that is, a computation on integers, with a syntax resembling other programming languages. This syntax is mostly used for assignments and in conditionals. This only exists in ksh/bash/zsh, not in plain sh.

What does that mean? Is the value of `x` toggled now and nothing else happened? In what case does this condition return `false`?

Comment: When doing an *assignment* within a if predicate, many compilers will emit a **warning** because it is likely that what was intended was an *equality* check, and a typo was made.  The extra parens tells the compiler "Intentionally doing an assignment, don't warn me about it."

Comment: Are you asking about C++ (which is your tag) or shell scripting languages (which is what your quotes are about)

Comment: [C++] It's an attempt to stop the compiler warning about a common (but legal) mistake of assigning rather than testing for equality in an if statement.

Comment: Don't expect that any given sequence of characters has the same meaning in all languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does the same thing as `if(x = !x)` does. However, because it is very easy to accidentally use `=` in place of `==`, compilers will warn you when you're using an assignment inside of an `if` statement. That warning doesn't get displayed if the assignment expression is inside of a *second* set of parenthesis.

So that's the point of the extra parens: to tell the compiler/reader that the writer *really* meant to use assignment rather than equality testing.

Comment: It's still terrible style.`x = !x;` first, then `if (x)` is way more readable.

Comment: @Jeffrey People are strange ;)

Comment: Note that neither the warning nor its suppression is part of the language definition. This is a compiler thing, not a language thing.